# Android client doesn't show message send by UWP Tcp server

Tags: c#, android, tcp, uwp

I have an asynchronous TCP server for a UWP running on my pc and an Android TCP client.
Server receives client message but it sends the line back to the client only when I close server application. I have triend Android client with an another TCP server (I used a TcpListener object) and it has worked properly.

How can I send the line back to the client as soon as server gets the message?

Here's TCP server:

```
        private async void StartServer()
        {
            try
            {
                //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
                StreamSocketListener socketListener  = new StreamSocketListener();

                //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
                socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

                //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port.
                await socketListener.BindServiceNameAsync("9999");

                TxtServer.Text = " SERVER RUNNNING...";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TxtError.Text = e.Message;
            }
        }

        private async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Read line from the remote client.
            Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inStream);
            request = await reader.ReadLineAsync();

            //Send the line back to the remote client.
            Stream outStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outStream);

            await writer.WriteLineAsync(request); 
            await writer.FlushAsync();
        }
```

and here's TCP client:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    TextView textResponse;
    EditText editTextAddress, editTextPort;
    Button buttonConnect, buttonClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);
        editTextPort = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
        buttonConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.connect);
        buttonClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
        textResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.response);

        buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(buttonConnectOnClickListener);

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textResponse.setText("");
            }});
    }


    OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener =
            new OnClickListener(){
                String tMsg = "TEST";

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0)
                {
                    MyClientTask myClientTask = new MyClientTask(editTextAddress.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(editTextPort.getText().toString()), tMsg);
                    myClientTask.execute();
                }};


    public class MyClientTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;
        String response = "";
        String msgToServer;

        MyClientTask(String addr, int port, String msgTo)
        {
            dstAddress = addr;
            dstPort = port;
            msgToServer = msgTo + "\n";
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            Socket socket = null;
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                if(msgToServer != null){
                    dataOutputStream.writeBytes(msgToServer);
                }
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead;
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                }

            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if(socket != null){
                    try
                    {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            textResponse.setText(response);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens now: Your client sends a line.
The server reads that line.
The server sends a line back.
The client does not try to read a line but continuously reads from the input stream.

You should let the client read a line to. Use 'readLine()'.

And what is UWP?

Comment: Thanks but I tried to change 'inputStream.read(buffer)' into 'inputStream.readLine(buffer)' but it doens't find readLine() method.. UWP stands for Universal Winodws Platform

Comment: Then add a BufferedInputReader which does have readLine(). You can find so many examples on this site. Or make your own readLine. It's not much work. Please change the subject of your post as you know now that the client is the culprit.

Comment: Ok, I should have solved. The problem was the while loop in the client. I've removed it  and I kept these instruction                                           bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");